# EF6 application crashes when run from network share

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crash

I wrote an application which makes use of .NET FW 4.5.1 and EF6. I have the problem that the application itself can be started when it is copied to a network share, but as soon as the first call to the database is made, the application crashes, yet this only happens on some computers in the network and I have absolutely no idea what the reason might be. If the application is run from a local drive on the same computer, it works as expected.

Update: I uploaded the full entry from the event viewer here: http://pastebin.com/dgs6nLxc

Comment: What do you mean by crash; can you please be more specific. What are the errors you are seeing?

Comment: By crash I mean that I get the "the application has caused an error and must be closed" screen. I uploaded the full eventvwr entry to pastebin and updated the question accordingly.